# Travel to and from Mexico

Tags: mexico

I was offered a chance to hunt deer in Mexico. I do not have a passport yet. Can I re-enter the U.S. with my state issued driver's license and a certified copy of my birth certificate?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Your question would be strengthened if you could [edit] it to provide more details, for example, what is your citizenship? How to you plan to travel to and from Mexico? Is your driver's license an Enhanced Driver's License? Are you a member of Global Entry, SENTRI, or another Trusted Traveler Program?

Comment: With what documents do you intend to enter Mexico, if you haven't got a passport?

Comment: You are required to hold a passport (or a US Passport card) to _enter_ Mexico